# Indexing MongoDB collection in Java

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial, mongodb-java, mongodb-indexes

I am creating a collection in `MongoDB` in the following way and I want to create a `2dsphere` index on location field of this collection from `Java` code. But I am not able to do so.

`collection.ensureIndex()` method expects a `DBObject` as a parameter but I cannot pass location to it.

How do I create `collection.ensureIndex({"location" : "2dsphere"})` in `Java` code?
`MongoDB` allows me to do so in command prompt. But, I want to index it through code written in Java.

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("attr1", nextLine[0])
                              .append("attr2", nextLine[1])
                              .append("edge-metro-code", nextLine[6])
                              .append("location", new BasicDBObject("type", "Point")
                                                            .append("coordinates",latLong)) 
                              .append("attr3", nextLine[9])
                              .append("attr4", nextLine[10])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should construct a new `DBObject` that represents your index. See the code bellow:

```
DBObject index2d = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("location", "2dsphere").get();
DBCollection collection = new Mongo().getDB("yourdb").getCollection("yourcollection");
collection.ensureIndex(index2d);
```

Comment: how do I use $near for the collection built with above structure of the document? I want to run a query from java which has $near in it. I tried QueryBuilder and BasicDbObject but could not find a right solution for it. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

`ensureIndex()` has been deprecated now. You should use `createIndex()` instead:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DBCollection test = mongoClient.getDB("testdb").getCollection("test");
test.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("location","2dsphere"));
```

Comment: can you please share the doc link saying __deprecated__?